# Is "Uncharted Tales" related in any way to the main comic book series?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, farscape

I'm currently reading the Farscape comic book series, and I've read TBOTEOTB, "Strange Detractors", "Gone And Back" and "Tangled Roots" already. I see that there are two side series available. For one, "Farscape: Scorpius", it's clear that this directly ties into the main storyline, and should be read before TWFTUT (or even before "Compulsions"). But for "Uncharted Tales", I don't know whether it's related in any way to the main story. Since UT is set during season 3 of the television series, whereas all the others are set after the end of the television series, it would seem to me that UT is essentially completely separate and won't be referenced from the main comic book series.

Without providing any spoilers, can you let me know whether "Uncharted Tales" needs to be read at some point during reading of the main books in order for things to make sense? Or is it just totally separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a late one - no, the three Uncharted Tales (D'Argo's Trial, D'Argo's Quest, D'Argo's Lament) are totally separate things. From what I recall, one is set season 3, one during season 3, and the other between seasons 3 and 4.